# Use URL to fetch data from database in php

Tags: php

I need to make search on a homepage , when I enter something on the search bar and when I click on submit the URL should like this : "findjob.php?keyword=softwaredeveloper" , but on the next it comes like this "findjob.php?keyword=". It seemed like the value from the previous page is not passing to the next page.
Below there is a sample code

```
 <form method="GET" action="findjob.php"> 
      <?php
            
       echo '<input class="form-control10 w-25 searchbar" name="schbyTtle"  placeholder="Job Title Or Job Category">';
              echo '<a class="btn myButton5 btn-outline-secondary" name="btnfind" href="findjob.php?keyword='.$_GET["schbyTtle"]. '" type="Submit">Find Job</a>';
            ?>
          </form>
```

Comment: `<a>` doesn't submit a form, it's a simple link - use a `<button>` instead. There also is no element named `keyword` in your form. https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php could help

Comment: As an aside... This has nothing to do with PHP, and the PHP code shown is superfluous.  All you have here is a simple HTML form.

Comment: You should also never output user data (like from `$_GET`, `$_POST`, cookies etc) as is. Always run it through [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities) or [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), or you risk [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up *forms* with *links*.  There is no "submit *link*" on a form.  It's a submit *button*:

```
<form method="GET" action="findjob.php"> 
  <input class="form-control10 w-25 searchbar" name="schbyTtle" placeholder="Job Title Or Job Category">
  <button class="btn myButton5 btn-outline-secondary" name="btnfind" type="submit">Find Job</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the button would "submit" the form, which performs a GET request to `findjob.php` and includes the form element key/value pairs on that GET request.

Note that "keyword" is *not* the name of your `<input>`.  So the resulting URL would use "schbyTtle" as the key instead.  If you want to change that, simply change the `name` of that `<input>` to match what you need.

Comment: ok thanks , I was mixing a lot of unneccessary stuff.